# how to delete some of the rows in first file based on information from a second file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this:

file 1:

```
    1   2       0.000
    1   3       0.213
    1   4       0.014
    1   5       0.001
    1   6       0.555
    1   7       0.509
    1   8       0.509
    3   4       0.995
    3   5       0.323
    3   6       0.555
    3   7       0.225
    3   8       0.000
    4   5       0.095
    4   6       0.058
    4   7       0.335
    4   8       0.000
    5   6       0.995
    5   7       0.658
    5   8       0.000
    6   7       0.431
    6   8       0.000
    7   8       0.000
```

and file 2 :

```
1
3 
4
5 6 7
```

I want keep those rows in file 1 in which pair numbers are observed together in a row at file2. here only 5, 6 and 7 are observed together in file 2. therefore each pair of those numbers should be remained in file1. so out put is:

```
5   6       0.995
5   7       0.658
6   7       0.431
```

any suggestion(by considering that the real data is huge and numbers may not begin from 1) ?

Comment: can there be more than 3 numbers in a line in second file?

Comment: also, seems like 1st/2nd column numbers are sorted both row wise and column wise, is that always true?

Comment: If the real data is *huge*, I'd consider using at least a small perl script instead of awk/cut (because traversing file 2 each time is slow and makes it quadratic), and if it's *really huge*, I'd write a C program. It's also important to have an idea how large these numbers can get, especially those in file 2.

Comment: @dirkt I don't think that `perl` can be faster than `awk`, see benchmarks in my answer.

Comment: @rudimeier, agree `awk` is usually faster than `perl`, but I feel like someone with better experience would be able to write a `perl` solution much faster than mine :)

Comment: @rudimeier sure it can. It just depends on what you're doing. Perl should be faster than `awk` if you're trying to match a regular expression across an entire line (as opposed to a specific field) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `perl` solution is okay. Assumes that column1 and column2 data in file1 are ordered such that value in column1 is always less than column2

```
$ perl -lane '
    if(!$nf)
    {
        if($#F > 0)
        {
            foreach $i (0..$#F)
            {
                $h{"-$F[$i]-$F[$_]-"}++ foreach ($i+1..$#F)
            }
        }
        $nf++ if eof;
    }
    else
    {
        print if $h{"-$F[0]-$F[1]-"}
    }
' file2 file1
    5   6       0.995
    5   7       0.658
    6   7       0.431
```

- First a hash of keys is built on file2 in pairs (again assuming numbers are arranged in increasing order)

  - the two columns values are surrounded by `-` to prevent possible mismatch, like `11` and `20` vs `1` and `120`
- Then for file1 lines, print the line if key exists

If `file2` is changed as

```
$ cat file2
1
3 4
5 6 7 8

$ perl -lane '
    if(!$nf)
    {
        if($#F > 0)
        {
            foreach $i (0..$#F)
            {
                $h{"-$F[$i]-$F[$_]-"}++ foreach ($i+1..$#F)
            }
        }
        $nf++ if eof;
    }
    else
    {
        print if $h{"-$F[0]-$F[1]-"}
    }
' file2 file1
    3   4       0.995
    5   6       0.995
    5   7       0.658
    5   8       0.000
    6   7       0.431
    6   8       0.000
    7   8       0.000
```

Comment: This code does nothing on my system (perl 5.18.1). But my perl knowledge is too limited to debug that. Looks like the code is only executed once, not for each line.

Comment: @rudimeier, mystery solved I think.. no wonder I've others complain in some form or other before too.. need to explicitly add `-n` option for that version.. can you try with `perl -nale` ?

Answer (score 3):

Using awk.

First awk command creates a file with all pairs. Second awk command reads the pairs file once into an array and then prints all matching lines.

```
awk 'NF>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++) print $i,$j;}' file2 > /tmp/pairs
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline <"/tmp/pairs") > 0) pair[$1,$2]=1; close("/tmp/pairs")} ($1,$2) in pair' file1
```

The second command may need much memory! If the files are ordered then we could avoid the array somehow, reading both files simultaneously. Note I'm using two commands to be able to review the pairs file before the final run.

Here the same code as a single command and readable formatted:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    f="file2"
    while((getline <f) > 0)
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++)
          pair[$i,$j]=1;
    close(f);
  }
  ($1,$2) in pair
' file1
```

**FYI** I've run some benchmarks on file1 (22 mill. lines), file2 (4 mill lines) which produces 2 mill. lines output.

- gawk: 9.6 secs, 275M memory
- mawk: 20.7 secs, 134M memory
- Sundeep's perl answer: 31.9 sec, 231M memory

Comment: to avoid tmp file, `awk 'NF>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++)print "^ *"$i" *"$j" ";}' file2 | grep -f- file1`

Comment: my `grep -f` is useless. It needs 100's of times more time and also memory! I'll remove that from my answer.

Comment: might interest you in knowing why grep is slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893789/why-is-grep-so-slow-and-memory-intensive-with-w-flag